# I can't find my error in this Scheme program for calculate PI

Tags: math, scheme, sicp

I am doing a Monte Carlo experiment to calculate an approximation of PI. From SICP:

> The Monte Carlo method consists of
>   choosing sample experiments at random
>   from a large set and then making
>   deductions on the basis of the
>   probabilities estimated from
>   tabulating the results of those
>   experiments. For example, we can
>   approximate  using the fact that
>   6/pi^2 is the probability that two
>   integers chosen at random will have no
>   factors in common; that is, that their
>   greatest common divisor will be 1. To
>   obtain the approximation to , we
>   perform a large number of experiments.
>   In each experiment we choose two
>   integers at random and perform a test
>   to see if their GCD is 1. The fraction
>   of times that the test is passed gives
>   us our estimate of 6/pi^2, and from
>   this we obtain our approximation to
>   pi.

But when I run my program I obtain values like 3.9...

Here is my program:

```
(define (calculate-pi trials)
  (define (this-time-have-common-factors?)
    (define (get-rand)
      (+ (random 9999999999999999999999999999999) 1))
    (= (gcd (get-rand) (get-rand)) 1))
  (define (execute-experiment n-times acc)
    (if (> n-times 0)
        (if (this-time-have-common-factors?)
            (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) acc)
            (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) (+ acc 1)))
        acc))
  (define n-success (execute-experiment trials 0))
  (define prob (/ n-success trials))
  (sqrt (/ 6 prob)))
```

My interpreter is MIT/GNU 7.7.90

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't get your code to run in DrScheme. Here's the error code: define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found at least one extra part in: (define (execute-experiment n-times acc) (if (> n-times 0) (if (this-time-have-common-factors?) (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) acc) (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) (+ acc 1))) acc))

So make sure that conditional is doing what you think it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: It's not helpful, but your question made me think of this: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi-by-Throwing-Frozen-Hot-Dogs.  If  I can't help, at least I can offer a laugh.

Comment: Those last two `define`s aren't valid because they need to evaluate previous definitions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, to answer your question directly, you have the if-statement backwards; it should be this way.

```
    (if (this-time-have-common-factors?)
        (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) (+ acc 1)
        (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) acc))
```

So you're calculating 1 - 6/π<sup>2</sup> in the limit as the # of trials approaches infinity. This yields "pi" = sqrt(6/(1 - 6/π<sup>2</sup>)) = sqrt(6π<sup>2</sup>/(π<sup>2</sup>-6)) = 3.911).

---

Let's take a step back here, though, and look at what the Monte Carlo method does for us with this calculation (hint: expect very slow convergence. How many times are you running it?)...

Each trial either gives us 0 or 1, with probability p = 6/π<sup>2</sup>. This is an example of a [Bernoulli process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process), which has, for the number of 1's *m* in a number of trials *n*, a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Consider ρ = m/n, the fraction of times passing the common-divisors test. This a has mean value of p and a variance of p(1-p)/n, or std dev σ<sub>ρ</sub> = sqrt(p(1-p)/n). For n = 10000, you should expect a std dev of 0.00488. [95% of the time you will be within 2 std devs of the mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_confidence_intervals), and 5% of the time you'll be outside 2 std devs, or between 0.5982 and 0.6177. So an estimate of π from this method, given n=10000, will be between 3.117 and 3.167 95% of the time and outside this range 5% of the time.

If you want increase the number of trials by 100, that reduces std dev by a factor of 10 and the estimate of π gets narrowed between 3.1391 and 3.1441 with 95% confidence.

Monte Carlo methods are nice for a rough estimate but they need LOTS and lots of trials for an accurate answer, and usually reach a point of diminishing returns.

Not that this is a fruitless way to approximate pi, just be aware of the issue.

Comment: > How many times are you running it?
(calculate-pi 99999999)
  1 ]=> ;Value: 3.141544196485725

Answer (score 3):

I find my error. 
Thanks to all.
I was incrementing the successful cases in the wrong place.

The corrected code is:

```
(define (calculate-pi trials)
  (define (this-time-have-common-factors?)
    (define (get-rand)
      (+ (random 9999999) 1))
    (= (gcd (get-rand) (get-rand)) 1))
  (define (execute-experiment n-times acc)
    (if (> n-times 0)
        (if (this-time-have-common-factors?)
            (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) (+ acc 1))
            (execute-experiment (- n-times 1) acc))
        acc))
  (define n-success (execute-experiment trials 0))
  (define prob (/ n-success trials))
  (sqrt (/ 6 prob)))
```